# How to evaluate the following integral which cannot be simply evaluated by residue theorem.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

> Evaluate $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x-i\omega} dx$$ where $\omega$ is real and $\omega\ne 0$.

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3GV9.png)

Comment: Either not all quantities are real, or the question is posed by a person with no regard for extremely canonical notation.

Comment: @TheCount I am sure all that's meant is that $x$ and $\omega$ are real, not that $i$ is.

Comment: @user1728 I am also sure of that, and am encouraging the OP to use more precise language.

Comment: What is your $\omega$?

Comment: Thanks very much. It is my fault to say something so unprecisely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the Fourier transform:
$$\mathcal Ff(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)e^{-2i\pi\xi x}dx$$
Then let $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ and $g(x)=\frac 1 {x+i\omega}$.
Then, by  Plancherel's theorem, $$\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx=\int_{\mathbb R}\mathcal F(f)(\xi)\overline{\mathcal F(g)(\xi)}d\xi$$
Let's assume first that $\omega > 0$ (to compute the value for a negative $\omega$, replace $\omega$ by  $-\omega$ and conjugate the result). Now, [it's well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Square-integrable_functions,_one-dimensional) that $$\mathcal F(f)(\xi)=\sqrt{\pi}e^{-\pi^2\xi^2} \quad\text{and}\quad \mathcal F(g)(\xi)=-2\pi ie^{-2\pi\omega\xi}H(\xi)$$
where $H$ is the [Heaviside  step  function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).
Therefore, $$\begin{split}
\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x-i\omega}dx &= 2i\pi^{\frac 3 2}\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-\pi^2\xi^2-2\pi\omega\xi}d\xi\\
&=2\pi^{\frac 3 2}e^{\omega^2}\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-(\pi\xi+\omega)^2}d\xi\\
&=2i\sqrt{\pi}e^{\omega^2}\int_{\omega}^{+\infty}e^{-u^2}du\\
&=2i\sqrt{\pi}e^{\omega^2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2\text{erfc}(\omega)\right)
\end{split}$$
where erfc is the [complementary error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfc.html).
Remembering that for negative $\omega$, we can replace by $-\omega$ and conjugate, we conclude that

$$\boxed{
\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x-i\omega}dx =\text{sgn}(\omega)i\pi e^{\omega^2}\text{erfc}(|\omega|)}$$

Comment: This is not correct for negative $\omega$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that $\frac{1}{x-i\omega}=\frac{x+i\omega}{x^2+\omega^2}$.  Hence, exploiting symmetry we find that for $\omega\ne0$

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x-i\omega}\,dx=i2\omega \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2+\omega^2}\,dx\tag1$$

Next, we let $F(a)$ be given by

$$F(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-ax^2}}{x^2+\omega^2}\,dx\tag2$$

Differentiating $(2)$ with respect to $a$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
F'(a)&=-\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2e^{-ax^2}}{x^2+\omega^2}\,dx\\\\
&=-\int_0^\infty \frac{(x^2+\omega^2-\omega^2)e^{-ax^2}}{x^2+\omega^2}\,dx\\\\
&=-\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2}\,dx+\omega^2 F(a)
\end{align}$$

Therefore, $F(a)$ satisfies the ODE

$$F'(a)-\omega^2 F(a)=-\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2\sqrt a}\tag3$$

with $F(0)=\frac{\pi}{2|\omega|}$.

It is straightforward to find the solution of $(3)$ with the given initial condition is can be written

$$F(a)=-\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}e^{\omega^2 x}\int_0^a \frac{e^{-\omega^2 x}}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx+\frac{\pi}{2|\omega|}e^{\omega^2 x}\tag4$$

Enforcing the substitution $x\to x^2/\omega^2$ in the integral on the right-hand side of $(4)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
F(a)&=-\frac{\sqrt \pi}{\omega}e^{\omega^2 a}\text{sgn}(\omega)\int_0^{|\omega| \sqrt a} e^{-x^2}\,dx+\frac{\pi}{2|\omega|}e^{\omega^2 a}\\\\
&=-\frac{\pi}{2\omega}e^{\omega^2 a}\text{sgn}(\omega)\text{erf}(|\omega |\sqrt a)+\frac{\pi}{2|\omega|}e^{\omega^2 a}\tag5
\end{align}$$

Setting $a=1$ in $(5)$ and substituting the result into $(1)$, we arrive at the identity for $\omega\ne0$

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x-i\omega}\,dx=i\pi e^{\omega^2}\text{sgn}(\omega)\left(1-\text{erf}(|\omega|)\right)=i\pi e^{\omega^2}\text{sgn}(\omega)\text{erfc}(|\omega|)$$

Comment: Thanks, I am too narrowed to consider only how to change the contour and using integration technicals, your answer helps a lot and not merely in this single question !

Comment: This is not correct for negative $\omega$.

Comment: Hi Rob.  Yes, correct.  I've edited accordingly.

Comment: One further small correction: the integral is negative imaginary for $\omega\lt0$ and for $\omega=0$, the PV is $0$.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks Rob.  I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x-i\omega}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{(x+i\omega)\,e^{-x^2}}{x^2+\omega^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag1\\
&=i\omega\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\,e^{-x^2}}{x^2+\omega^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag2\\
&=i\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\,e^{-\omega^2x^2}}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: make denominator real
$(2)$: use symmetry; at this point, the function is odd
$(3)$: substitute $x\mapsto\omega x$; this makes the function even

For $\omega\gt0$, define
$$
I(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\,e^{-\omega^2x^2}}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag4
$$
Then, we have
$$
I'(\omega)-2\omega I(\omega)=-2\sqrt\pi\tag5
$$
with an integrating factor of $e^{-\omega^2}$, we get
$$
\left[e^{-\omega^2}I(\omega)\right]'=-2\sqrt\pi e^{-\omega^2}\tag6
$$
Integrating, we have
$$\newcommand{\erfc}{\operatorname{erfc}}\newcommand{\sgn}{\operatorname{sgn}}
I(\omega)=\pi e^{\omega^2}\erfc(\omega)\tag7
$$
Making the function odd yields, for all $\omega\ne0$,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x-i\omega}\,\mathrm{d}x=i\sgn(\omega)\,\pi e^{\omega^2}\erfc(|\omega|)}\tag8
$$
Note that $\sgn(0)=0$ also gives the proper Cauchy Principal Value for $\omega=0$.

Comment: This is effectively the same as mine other than the correction for negative values of $\omega$.

Comment: In a sense, yes, but it avoids the introduction of the variable $a$, which is a bit cleaner.

Comment: @MarkViola: the more I look at your answer, the more I see that our answers are not so similar. Although we both differentiate under the integral to get a differential equation, the differential equations are quite different. So I don't think that our answers are "effectively the same".

Comment: Yes, I understand your point.  In using "effectively," I referred to (1) differentiating under the integral and (2) solving an ensuing ODE.  But yes, they are not identical.